# JBoss not detecting application deployment

Tags: deployment, jboss, struts2, restart

I have a java webapp deployed on jboss 4.2.3 which used to use the Struts 2.0 library. I recently upgraded it to Struts 2.3.4 and updated all of the code to use the new version.

On my local workstation, I started getting errors referring to code that I removed which depended on the old version of Struts. These errors disappeared when I cleared the contents of the JBoss precompiled JSP folder located at:

```
jboss\server\<name_of_my_instance>\work\jboss.web\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp
```

Today, I deployed the new version to our production webserver. I cleared the contents of the JSP precompile directory (listed above) and restarted the webserver.

Whenever a user goes to a page which I modified to remove the Struts 2.0 tags (and replaced them with Struts 2.3.4), they get a server error about Struts being unable to find the Struts 2.0 files. I cannot reproduce these errors on my local instance.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be configured differently between my local and production webservers? How can I force the production server to read the new webapp that I deployed?

Note - I am using an exploded deployment (not a WAR) and the problematic pages use include files. Here is an example:

**myInclude.inc**

```
<s:if test="%{userIsAdmin}">
    <%-- Show some toolbar --%>
</s:if>
```

**myFile.jsp**

```
<%@ include file="myInclude.inc"%>
```

Accessing myFile.jsp produces a stack trace since JBoss does not seem to detect that the myInclude.inc file has changed. The old version of myInclude.inc depends on the old Struts 2.0 and the new version does not.

Comment: Include the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. My deployment process was broken and the include file wasn't actually making it out to the webserver.

Comment: Could you please explain what was broken & how you fixed it so people with a similar problem can do the same?